# How do you properly load a vertical list of images without squeeezing their text (image attached)

Tags: php, html, css

[image: bootstrap card]

When I load my page I have a card with a vertical list of images. Because images take time to load, the text loads faster and therefore it is squeezed as seen in the attached screenshot. Is it possible for the text to appear in the right position while the image keeps loading? How can I solve this?
I'm using php for the loop but I believe this is purely an html issue.
I'm looping the following code inside a `<div class="card-body">`

```
<div id="<?php echo $imgid; ?>" class="col-lg-6 col-xxl-12 mb-3">
 <div class="row">           
  <div class="col-12">
   <div class="position-relative h-sm-100">
    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
     <img class="img-fluid fit-cover w-sm-100 h-sm-100 rounded-1 absolute-sm-centered" style="filter: brightness(70%);" src="img/<?php echo $imgfile; ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="badge rounded-pill bg-gradient text-dark position-absolute bottom-0 start-0 ms-2 mb-2 fs--2 z-index-2">
     <?php echo $topic; ?> | <?php echo $subtopic; ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to somehow reserve a place for images.

You can specify the size of images in HTML size.

```
<img width="480" height="360" src="image.jpg">
```

You can download the CSS code in advance and specify the image sizes in it. It is extremely important that the CSS code is loaded before the HTML download is complete.

```
img { width: 480px; height: 360px }
```

You can delay the loading of images that are not visible on the first screen of the site without scrolling. This method is called lazy loading.

```
<img loading="lazy" src="image.jpg">
```

You can also upload not full-fledged images at the beginning, but stubs. Low resolution images tend to be small and load quickly.

Comment: Wow. Is this the only way? If my image size changes in several screens then I need to create several CSS lines for each image? thanks for the tip.

Comment: No, there are other approaches. For example, you can prepare images with the desired resolution on the server side. But you need to reserve space for images anyway. You can use `media-queries`. There is a `picture` element, and finally there are `media attributes` for the `img` tag, but they are less flexible. Modern browsers support the css `aspect-ratio` property.